# CSS3 animation on firefox working but in chrome its bugged

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation

I was doing my css3 animation and after when i had been testing i saw , When you are in firefox its clearly animation , but in chrome animation doesnt work . 
My code is there : 
Thanks.
(You can might see something (in chrome) if you click on links).

http://jsfiddle.net/w6dnndqh/4/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="menu"> 
            <a href="#"><div class="logo"></div></a>
            <ul class="social">
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="gallery">
            <div id="center" class="col-md-10">
                <div id="header">
                    <h1>Gallery</h1>
                    <span id="underline"></span>
                    <ul class="gallery-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PERSONAL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">WEDDINGS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="photos" class="col-md-12 ">
                    <div class="photo tall one"></div>
                    <div class="photo small two">
                        <div class="photo-small-one"></div>
                        <div class="photo-small-two"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="photo small three">
                        <div class="photo-small-three"></div>
                        <div class="photo-small-four"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="photo tall four"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#menu{
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #181818;
    color: white;
    border-right:3px solid white; 
}
#menu .logo{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:url("..//img/icon-h&h-logo.png");
    background-size: 160px 120px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    clear: both;
    width: 160px;
    height: 120px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#menu ul.menu {
    position: relative;
    top:40px;
    width: 100%;
    left: -40px;
}
#menu ul.menu li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    width: 247px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#menu ul.menu li{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 18pt;
    width: 277px;
    font-family: "timeburnerregular" , sans-serif;
    padding:3px 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    color: white;

}
#menu ul.menu li a:before{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    content:"";
    width: 0%;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #181818;
    display: block;
    right:0px;
    top:-5px;
}
#menu ul.menu li a:hover:before{
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-animation-name: slide;
            animation-name: slide;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .4s;
            animation-duration: .4s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
#menu ul.menu li a:hover{
    color:black;
    -webkit-animation-name:color;
            animation-name:color;
    -webkit-animation-duration:.6s;
            animation-duration:.6s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide{
    from{width: 0%;}
    to{width: 100%;}
}
@keyframes slide{
    from{width: 0%;}
    to{width: 100%;}
}
@keyframes color{
    from{color: white;}
    to{color: black;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes color{
    from{color: white;}
    to{color: black;}
}
#menu ul.social{
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: -28px;
}
#menu ul.social li{
    display: inline;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    margin:5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#menu ul.social li:nth-child(1){
    background:url("..//img/icon-facebook.png");
        background-size: cover;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition:.1s all ease-in-out;
            transition:.1s all ease-in-out;
}
#menu ul.social li:nth-child(1):hover{
    background:url("..//img/icon-facebook-color.png");
    background-size: cover;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition:.3s all ease-in-out;
            transition:.3s all ease-in-out;
}
#menu ul.social li:nth-child(2){
    background:url("..//img/icon-twitter.png");
        background-size: cover;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition:.1s all ease-in-out;
            transition:.1s all ease-in-out;
}
#menu ul.social li:nth-child(2):hover{
    background:url("..//img/icon-twitter-color.png");
    background-size: cover;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition:.3s all ease-in-out;
            transition:.3s all ease-in-out;
}
#menu ul.social li:nth-child(3){
    background:url("..//img/icon-google+.png");
        background-size: cover;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition:.1s all ease-in-out;
            transition:.1s all ease-in-out;
}
#menu ul.social li:nth-child(3):hover{
    background:url("..//img/icon-google+-color.png");
    background-size: cover;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition:.3s all ease-in-out;
            transition:.3s all ease-in-out;
}
#menu ul.social li:nth-child(4){
    background:url("..//img/icon-instagram.png");
        background-size: cover;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition:.1s all ease-in-out;
            transition:.1s all ease-in-out;
}
#menu ul.social li:nth-child(4):hover{
    background:url("..//img/icon-instagram-color.png");
    background-size: cover;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition:.3s all ease-in-out;
            transition:.3s all ease-in-out;
}
#menu ul.social li:nth-child(5){
    background:url("..//img/icon-youtube.png");
        background-size: cover;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition:.1s all ease-in-out;
            transition:.1s all ease-in-out;
}
#menu ul.social li:nth-child(5):hover{
    background:url("..//img/icon-youtube-color.png");
    background-size: cover;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition:.3s all ease-in-out;
           transition:.3s all ease-in-out;
}
/* ABOUT ------*/

#content{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 280px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: auto;
}
#content.about{
        background:url("..//img/image-bg.jpg");
}
#content:after{
    content: "";
    background:url("..//img/pattern.gif");
    opacity: .3;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}
#about{
    width: 88%;
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction:normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction:row;
        -ms-flex-direction:row;
            flex-direction:row;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -webkit-justify-content:center;
        -ms-flex-pack:center;
            justify-content:center;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    -webkit-align-items:center;
        -ms-flex-align:center;
            align-items:center;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#about .photo{
    background:url("..//img/image-photographer.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 300px;
    height: 360px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
#about .photo:after{
    content: "";
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -20px;
    display: block;
}
#about .text{
    float: left;
    background-color:white;
    max-width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    font-family: "timeburnerregular",sans-serif;
    padding-left: 45px;
}
#about .text h2.hello{
    font-size: 32pt;
}
#about .text h1{
    font-size: 20pt;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    color:#646464;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
#about .text a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
#about .text h1 b{
    color: #323232;
}
#about .text h2.iwas{
    font-size: 20pt;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: "timeburnerregular",sans-serif;

}
#about .contact-text{
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    left:100px;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    color:white;
}
#about .contact-text img{
    float: left;
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    position: relative;
    top:9px;
}
#about .contact-text a,
#about .contact-text p{
    float: left;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-family: "timeburnerregular",sans-serif;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    -webkit-align-items:center;
        -ms-flex-align:center;
            align-items:center;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition:.8s all ease-in-out;

}
#about .contact-text a:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30%;
    left: 45%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 0%;
    margin:0 auto;
    -webkit-transition:.3s all ease-in-out;
}
#about .contact-text a:hover:after{
    -webkit-animation-name: underline;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -webkit-transition:.8s all ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes underline{
    from{width: 0%;}
    to{width: 45%;}
}
#about .contact-text span#vertical-line{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 60%;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    top:18px;
    margin: 0px 20px;
}
/*GALLERY*/
.gallery{
    background:url("..//img/image-bg-gallery.jpg");
}
#content #center{
    height: 100%;
}
#content #center #header{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "timeburnerregular",sans-serif;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top:100px;
}
#content #center #header h1{
    font-size: 32pt;
}
 #header span#underline{
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
ul.gallery-menu{
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul.gallery-menu li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-family: "Arial",sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}
ul.gallery-menu li a:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -24px;
    left: -20px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 0;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: -1;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
ul.gallery-menu li a:hover:before{
    background-color: orange;
    height: 80px;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideDown;
            animation-name: slideDown;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .4s;
            animation-duration: .4s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 ul.gallery-menu li a:hover{
    color:black;
            -webkit-animation-name:colortwo;
                    animation-name:colortwo;
    -webkit-animation-duration:.1s;
            animation-duration:.1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideDown{
    from{height: 0%;}
    to{height: 80px;}
}
@keyframes slideDown{
    from{height: 0%;}
    to{height: 80px;}
}
@keyframes colortwo{
    from{color: white;}
    to{color: black;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes colortwo{
    from{color: white;}
    to{color: black;}
}


ul.gallery-menu li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
#content #center #photos{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -webkit-justify-content:center;
        -ms-flex-pack:center;
            justify-content:center;
}
#content #center #photos .one{
    background:url("..//img/image-grill1.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
}
#photos .photo{
    margin:2px;
}
#photos .two{
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float: left;
}
#photos .two .photo-small-one{
    background: url("..//img/image-plate.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
#photos .two .photo-small-two{
    background: url("..//img/image-meadow.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
#photos .three{
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float: left;
}
#photos .three .photo-small-three{
    background: url("..//img/image-meadow1.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
#photos .three .photo-small-four{
    background: url("..//img/image-trophies.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
#content #center #photos .four{
    background:url("..//img/image-portrait.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
}
/* OPTIMALIZE FOR MOBILES*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px){
    #menu{
        float: none;
        height: auto;
        width: 101%;
    }
    #menu ul.menu{
        left:0;
        top:0;
    }
    #menu ul.menu li{
        position: static;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    #menu ul.social{
        left:-1%;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack:center;
        -webkit-justify-content:center;
            -ms-flex-pack:center;
                justify-content:center;
        background-color: black;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        padding-right: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    #menu ul.social li{
        margin: 5px 20px;
    }
    #content{
        position: static;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #content #center{
        height: 80vh;
    }
    #content #center #photos{
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w6dnndqh/4/

Comment: Edit your question **with the code** (not a link for it)

Comment: ....and a **reduced** piece of code at that...there's **way** to much there to wade through...we only need to see not working...not the whole page.